# Are there ways to modify/update xml files other than totally over writing the old file?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm working on a script which involves continuously analyzing data and outputting results in a multi-threaded way. So basically the result file(an xml file) is constantly being updated/modified (sometimes 2-3 times/per second).

I'm currently using `lxml` to parse/modify/update the xml file, which works fine right now. But from what I can tell, you have to rewrite the whole xml file even sometimes you just add one entry/sub-entry like `<weather content=sunny />` somewhere in the file. The xml file is growing bigger gradually, and so is the overhead.

As far as efficiency/resource is concerned, any other way to update/modify the xml file? Or you will have to switch to SQL database or similar some day when the xml file is too big to parse/modify/update?

Comment: You can _append_ to a file (on the filesystems I'm familiar with, anyway) as a special case. I doubt that's particularly helpful though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you generally cannot - and not just XML files, any file format.

You can only update "in place" if you overwite bytes exactly (i.e. don't add or remove any characters, just replace some with something of the same byte length).

Using a form of database sounds like a good option.

Comment: A database is especially nice for a multi-threaded application because all the hard synchronisation stuff (file locks, ACID, etc.) is already done for you. Databases don't have to be CPU-heavy networked things; SQLite uses plain files and it's very fast to boot.

Comment: @Li-aungYip: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm checking SQLite right now, and it seems pretty awesome for my script.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly sounds like you need some sort of database, as *Li-anung Yip* states this would take care of all kinds of nasty multi-threaded sync issues.

You stated that your data is gradually increasing? How is it being consumed? Are clients forced to download the entire result file each time?

Don't know your use-case but perhaps you could consider using an [ATOM feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) to distribute your data changes? Providing support for [Atom pub](http://atompub.org/) would also effectively REST enable your data. It's still XML, but in a standard's compliant format that is easy to consume and poll for changes.